# Why giving the train and test data helps to achieve more accuracy while fitting the model (LSTM) than using Timeseriesgenerators?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make a prediction model and if I try to fit the model using the x_train and Y_train it produces more accurate output than using train_generator and test_generator.

Getting x_test and y_test:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=123, shuffle=False)
```

Getting train and test generators:

```
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_train, y_train, length= win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch_size)
test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_test, y_test, length= win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Fitting the model with train and test data:

```
# Fitting the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size= 16, epochs = 34, shuffle = False)
```

Fitting the model with generators:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs = 34,
        validation_data = test_generator,
        shuffle= False)
```

so i tried using both methods and the 1st method gives the RMSE of 6.3454423 and the 2nd method gives the RMSE of 13.4363478. What might be the reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

You should split validation-data from test-data. in such a way that you should divide your dataset into three parts: training, validation and testing. The sameness of test and validation sets causes overfitting. If you have a small dataset, you can use cross validation. Also, the difference between the generated dataset and the original dataset is the main reason for changing the accuracy of the model.